# Symfony Ajax Request error 500

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, symfony

Hi everyone I come to you because I have a little problem with my ajax script I share my code and tell me if there is a problem thanks for advances, if you have any solution I thank you, the error made This is:

```
Argument 1 passed to App \ Repository \ ProductRepository :: findBySearch () must be of the string type, object given, called in C: \ wamp64 \ www \ Shop \ src \ Controller \ FrontController.php on line 201
```

my controller :

```
/**
     * @Route("/recherche/", name="search", methods="POST")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function search(Request $request): Response{

        $search = $this->createForm(SearchType::class);
        $search->handleRequest($request);

        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

           $value = $search['name'];
           $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class)->findBySearch($value);

           return new JsonResponse($result);
        }

        return $this->render('inc/search.html.twig', [
            'title' => 'Effectuer une recherche',
            'search' => $search->createView()
        ]);

    }
```

My repository in which the SQL query is performed :

```
/**
     * @param $value
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function findBySearch(string $value) {

        $bool = 1;
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->select('r')
            ->orwhere('r.name LIKE :chaine')
            ->orWhere('r.description LIKE :chaine')
            ->andWhere('r.isPublished = :bool')
            ->orderBy('r.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter(':chaine', '%'.$value.'%')
            ->setParameter(':bool', $bool)
            ->getQuery();

        try {
            return $query->getResult();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Problème' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

this is my code that allows me to make ajax requests

```
<!-- Modal Search -->
<div class="modal-search-header flex-c-m trans-04 js-hide-modal-search">
    <div class="container-search-header">
        <button class="flex-c-m btn-hide-modal-search trans-04 js-hide-modal-search">
            <img src="images/icons/icon-close2.png" alt="CLOSE">
        </button>
        <div id="resultat"></div>
         {{ form_start(search, {'method': 'POST', 'attr': {'class': 'wrap-search-header flex-w p-l-15', 'id': 'form'}}) }}
            <button class="flex-c-m trans-04">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
            </button>
            {{ form_widget(search.name) }}

        {{ form_end(search) }}
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#form").keypress(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                url:"{{ path('search') }}",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#search_name").html(data);
                    $.post( "{{ path('search') }}", function( data ) {
                        $( "#resultat" ).html( data );
                    });
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#search_name").html('Une erreur est survenue.');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
$value = $search['name'];
```

with

```
$value = $search->get('name')->getNormData();
```

Since `$search` is a `FormInterface` object, you won't get the submitted value just through `$search['name']`. You could call `$search->getData()` to get the whole form data OR `$search->get('YOUR_FIELD_NAME')->getNormData()` to get an specific value

Also, consider to wrap it with

```
if($search->isSubmitted()) {

   if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
     // ... 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help 
then the query in post works but the display of the data does not work it returns me an error 500 of the same type!

Comment: Did you inspect the 500 in debug bar? what value has `$result` variable? I would suggest you to temporarily remove the try/catch block in the `findBySearch()` method so you can see if `findBySearch()` fails

Comment: Thank you for your help it works well I have one last question in relation to my ajax script how to display the result? I get json but how do I display it?